# How does SelectMany work when source and target streams are the same in C# Reactive Framework?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I've got two `Subject`s, one that is a stream of person objects with ID, and one that is a stream of xref of IDs representing who has befriended whom.  Here's some simplified code.

```
class Program {
    static void Main() {
        // Set up observables
        var people = new Subject<Person>();
        var friendMap = new Subject<FriendMap>();
        var friendNotices = from p1 in people
                            from p2 in people
                            from pair in friendMap
                            where p1.Id == pair.Id1 && p2.Id == pair.Id2
                            select p1.Name + " befriended " + p2.Name;

        // Subscribe to log
        friendNotices.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

        // Add people
        people.OnNext(new Person(1, "Alice"));
        people.OnNext(new Person(2, "Bob"));

        // Add relationships
        friendMap.OnNext(new FriendMap(1, 2)); // => "Alice befriended Bob"
        friendMap.OnNext(new FriendMap(2, 1)); // Doesn't show up!
    }
}

class Person {
    public Person(int id, string name) {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name;
    public int Id;
}

class FriendMap {
    public FriendMap(int id1, int id2) {
        Id1 = id1;
        Id2 = id2;
    }
    public int Id1;
    public int Id2;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that sometimes adding an xref does not result in a `friendNotice` event.  In particular, it seems to fail if the person with Id2 was created *before* the person with Id1.

Is this a bug in Rx or a bug in my code?  Either way, how do I go about getting this to work?

("Befriending" is non-commutative in my application--Alice befriending Bob is a different relationship than Bob befriending Alice, so "just swap the IDs and retry" isn't a usable solution in my case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is a misunderstanding in how the SelectMany function works (this is the operator mapped to by the linq comprehension `from ... from ...`).

This construct takes each element from the source stream and projects it onto the target stream. It does this by creating a subscription on the target stream for each element of the source to service a projection.

Let's examine this using a little pseudo code. Consider just this part of your query:

```
from p1 in people
from p2 in people
```

For the moment, let's split the people stream into peopleA and peopleB:

```
from p1 in peopleA
from p2 in peopleB
```

If we now call:

```
peopleA.OnNext(Alice);
```

What actually happens is that a new subscription will be created on peopleB to service the projection of Alice onto peopleB. At this point, there are no elements in peopleB - so no projection will occur.

Now if we call:

```
peopleB.OnNext(Tom);
```

The projection from Alice -> peopleB will run and (Alice, Tom) will be output.

Now call:

```
peopleB.OnNext(Dick);
```

Now the projection from Alice -> peopleB continues so  (Alice, Dick) will be output.

Now call:

```
peopleA.OnNext(Bob);
```

Now a new subscription starts on peopleB for Bob - but nothing will be output until peopleB emits.

Now call:

```
peopleB.OnNext(Harry);
```

And with both the Alice and Bob subscriptions running we will get (Alice, Harry) and (Bob, Harry);

A simple example for you to try:

```
var source = new Subject<string>();
var source2 = new Subject<string>();

var res = from s in source
          from t in source2
          select s + " " + t;

res.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

source.OnNext("A"); 
source2.OnNext("1");
source2.OnNext("2");
source.OnNext("B");
source2.OnNext("3");
```

Will give the output:

```
A 1
A 2
A 3
B 3
```

Back to the "self SelectMany". Now it all starts getting a bit tricky. The key part is that the subscriptions being set up won't catch the "current" items triggering their set up. So lets label each part of the SelectMany A and B:

```
from p1 in people (call this A)
from p2 in people (call this B)
```

When we call:

```
people.OnNext(Alice);
```

A subscription for Alice on A will be made on B - but as it is made after Alice is emitted it won't catch her and nothing will be output.

Now we call:

```
people.OnNext(Bob);
```

The subscription for Alice will see Bob on B this causes (Alice, Bob) to be output. A subscription for Bob on A will be created on B but again nothing will be output as it misses the output of Bob.

This is what you are seeing. The only combination emitted is (Alice, Bob).

You can fix this though by having the people subject replay it's contents when a new subscription is set up. Modify the first part of your sample like this:

```
    // Set up observables
    var people = new Subject<Person>();
    var peopleR = people.Replay().RefCount();
    var friendMap = new Subject<FriendMap>();
    var friendNotices = from p1 in peopleR
                        from p2 in peopleR
                        from pair in friendMap
                        where p1.Id == pair.Id1 && p2.Id == pair.Id2
                        select p1.Name + " befriended " + p2.Name;
```

... but this isn't advisable if your stream is long running of course, as you are caching everything in memory.

As far as your particular problem goes, I think you'd be better off going a different way - but it's hard to be prescriptive without knowing what you are trying to achieve, and this is already quite a long post! One way to go would be to have a simple subscription to FriendMap entries and just look up the friend's names to output the message you want. (I'm probably missing something in the bigger picture!).

Hopefully you understand the issue with your approach though.

Comment: Okay, I had a feeling that's what was going on.  I thought I was going to have to essentially implement `Replay` from scratch.  After some googling it turns out there's a `ReplaySubject` class that makes your solution even easier.  I can even post to friendMap out-of-order now and everything still works.  Been contemplating this for a long time; happy to know it's built-in to the framework!